# Subtype Generator with fixed type variables

Tags: python, python-typing

Say I have a program with several generator functions that all have the return type `Generator[<type>, <type2>, None]` and I want to make an alias `SimpleGenerator[<type>, <type2>]` that is then expanded to the previous.

So for example

```py
def my_generator() -> Generator[int, str, None]:
    ...
```

could be written

```py
def my_generator() -> SimpleGenerator[int, str]:
    ...
```

I imagine the code might look something like (obviously incorrect python code)

```py
T1 = TypeVar('T1')
T1 = TypeVar('T2')
SimpleGenerator['T1', 'T2'] = Generator['T1', 'T2', None]
```

But I'm not finding an easy way of writing it, and if going all the way of defining a class that inherits from Generator:

```py
T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")
class SimpleGenerator(Generator["T1", "T2", None]):
    ...

def my_generator() -> SimpleGenerator[int, str]:
    ...
```

Then both mypy and pyright will not accept that as a return type for generators, saying

> The return type of a generator function should be "Generator" or one of its supertypes

and

> Return type of generator function must be "Generator" or "Iterable"

respectively.
Is this possible to do?

--

(Originally I wanted `Generator[<type>, None, None]` and the pyright error message helped me realize I could then just use `Iterable[<type>]` as the return type. But my curiousity remains so I modified the question.)

Comment: Can you provide a code example how you use the original `Generator` annotation and how you would use the `SimpleGenerator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your generator is not a class, but a method, and you annotate it with your type. So you should do something like this:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, 
Generator

T = TypeVar('T')

MyGenerator = Generator[T, None, None]

def my_generator() -> MyGenerator[str]:
    yield 'this'
    yield 'is'
    yield 'working'

print(' '.join(my_generator()))
```

Output:

```
python3.10 -m mypy test.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file

python test.py
this is working
```

Comment: I was maybe unclear but yeah I wasn't confused about the class/method distinction, and the class was all about creating a a type class that I could then give as type hint in my methods. But looks like it was super easy after all and I simple didn't need to specify the typevars in the left hand side when assigning to SimpleGenerator. Thanks!